# How can I add my own rating system?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add a rating system? My blog gets its posts from database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` longtext NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `posted_by` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

In index.php I call them using echo, everything works fine.

Example:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h1 style="color:white;" class="my-4"> My Blog
          </h1>
            <div class="card mb-4">
           <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
           <iframe style="border:0;" class="embed-responsive-item" width="450" height="240" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">Title</h2>
              <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">Footer</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Just search for "_php rating_" or "_jquery rating_" on web ;-). For example [this](https://www.codexworld.com/star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-php/), or [this](https://phppot.com/jquery/dynamic-star-rating-with-php-and-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

For Rating System create a table 
e.g. 
posts_rating having columns as 
id as int(auto incrememt), 
post_id as int, 
user_id as int(if applicable in your project)
rating as int

Then when a user wants to give rating insert value to the posts_rating table.

To display current rating for the post execute the sql statement:

select round(AVG(rating),1) as currentRating FROM post_rating WHERE post_id=".$post_id;