# How can I get the right blog post ID and add correctly the rate values?

Tags: php, mysql

Following on from [How can I add my own rating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956908/how-can-i-add-my-own-rating-system) I need some help with adding the correctly values to the "specified" blog post. It adds new rows in database instead adding the values of the correct post where rate has been submitted. I know why it adds new rows, I just don't know how can I make it to add rate values to the "specified" blog post ID.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` longtext NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `posted_by` longtext NOT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Index.php:

```
     <?php 
     while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
     ?>
    <div class="card mb-4">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe style="border:0;" class="embed-responsive-item" width="450" height="240" src="<?php echo $r['video']; ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $r['title']; ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo $r['text']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted"><?php echo $r['posted_by']; ?>
    </div>
    <form action="../functions/rate.php" method="POST" class="rate-system">
    <div class="select">
     <select name="slct" id="slct">
      <option>Vote for the post</option>
      <option name="awful" value="1">1 - Awful</option>
      <option name="bad" value="2">2 - Bad</option>
      <option name="good" value="3">3 - Good</option>
      <option name="cool" value="4">4 - Cool</option>
      <option name="awesome" value="5">5 - Awesome</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="submit-rate">
     <input class="rate-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add  rating"/>
   </div>
   </form>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Rate.php (Updated on 23.06.2018):

```
<?php 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "oregon";
    $dbname = "project";

        try {               
            $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
            if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "1") {
                $rate = "1";
            } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "2") {
                $rate = "2";
            } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "3") {
                $rate = "3";
            } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "4") {
                $rate = "4";
            } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "5") {
                $rate = "5";
            } else {
                $rate = "0";
            }
            $clicks = '1';
            $id = $_POST['post_id'];
            $sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE posts SET rate = :rate, clicks = :clicks WHERE id = :id");
            $sql->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $sql->bindParam(':rate', $rate, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sql->bindParam(':clicks', $clicks, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if ($sql->execute()) {
                echo "Record updated successfully"; 
            } else { 
                echo "Error updating record: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $connection = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: You're doing `INSERT` when you should be doing `UPDATE`?

Comment: $sql = ("UPDATE posts SET rate = '$rate', clicks = '1' WHERE id = 1");

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
}

Comment: I made it with update and now it works, but it still gives rating data only to the first post even if i rate on the second or the last no matter, all goes to the first and also if vote twice second vote replaces the first (Since I've set id to 1). I have no clue how to make the "id" work by getting the current id where rating button has been submitted.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">` Place this in your `<form>` and in your update query it would look like this `WHERE id = '$_POST['post_id']'` <- of course this is not secure and I'm pretty sure you understand what I mean from this.

Comment: yeah works properly, thank you :) . And no, I don't understnand , would you explain me please? And also why after each new update query old data is getting removed?

Comment: See my answer @Stephan82

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see if it works for you.

```
<?php 
    try {
        $sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE posts SET rate = :rate, clicks = :clicks WHERE id = :id");
        $sql->bindParam(':rate', $rate);
        $sql->bindParam(':clicks', $clicks);
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);    
        if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "1") {
            $rate = "1";
        } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "2") {
            $rate = "2";
        } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "3") {
            $rate = "3";
        } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "4") {
            $rate = "4";
        } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "5") {
            $rate = "5";
        } else {
            $rate = "none";
        }
        $clicks = '1';
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            echo "Record updated successfully"; 
        } else { 
            echo "Error updating record: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @JeanPaul98. I've edited the code and it adds rating without problem. As far as I am aware, we are using PDO instead, but it still updates data without saving the previous rate and clicks..

Comment: So you want it to update the current data but at the same time save the previous data? @Stephan882

Comment: Yeah @JeanPaul98 , but I have managed to fix that issue byself and of course that would not have happen without your help guys and I appreciate it, thanks. I've got another issue and I've posted another topic, I'll be thankful if we fix it since it's the latest things that is needed to be fixed ^^ :)